# Why is HttpContext.Current null during first request to an ASP.Net enabled WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have some WCF services that are hosted by IIS with ASP.Net compatibility turned on.

I have the following in my web.config:

< serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

And my service class is decorated with the following:

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

For some weird reason, the HttpContext.Current is null for the first request after the web app starts up.  The HttpContext.Current is not null for following requests as expected.

Does anyone have an idea why it isn't working for the very first request?

The call to HttpContext.Current is from within a custom UserNamePasswordValidator class I wrote to check creds stored in the database.

Comment: Do you mean that after the service runs, the first request to the service does not xt while you get the context during the next request(s)?

Comment: Yes.  The first request to one of the service methods after deploying new dlls or otherwise restarting the host asp.net app crashes with a null pointer on the HttpContext.Current call.  The 2nd and following requests to the service work just fine.

Comment: Question updated to include note about the custom UserNamePasswordValidator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the framework that was fixed in 4.0.  [more info](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/491844/when-using-asp-net-compatibility-mode-httpcontext-and-web-configs-arent-handled-properly-on-the-first-hit-only)

Comment: Can anyone provide a still working link to that topic? I got the same issues on a sharepoint site (which is 3.5) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7.0 integrated mode to host your application `HttpContext.Current` might not be initialized in `Application_Start` so if you are trying to access it there it will crash.

Comment: I'm not calling it from with the Application_Start event.  The UserNamePasswordValidator class is called by the WCF plumbing.

Comment: What happens if you deactivate the integrated mode in IIS and use classic mode instead?

Comment: Classic mode actually fixes the problem, but now I have the new problem of not being in integrated mode.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on why classic mode fixes it?

Comment: I explained in my answer why. Because HttpContext.Current might not be available in integrated mode during Application_Start. Then you said that it is called by the *WCF plumbing* which is not very precise for me. By the way probably off-topic but it is not recommended to use HttpContext.Current at all in a WCF service as it might be hosted in different environments, even in a console application and having your service depend on it is very bad. In WCF it is preferred to use [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx).

Comment: I am aware that this is frowned on, but my services will never be hosted outside of IIS.  I am using an IoC container that keeps per-request scoped objects in the HttpContext items collection.

Comment: I don't know enough about WCF to be more precise than "WCF plumbing".  I just put the type of my custom UserNamePasswordValidator in the config file and the framework calls the Validate method on it for every call.  I would expect this to not be associated with the Application_Start because the validator is invoked per service method call.